# my bootstrap 5 "col" class is not working?

Tags: layout, bootstrap-5

I want to create layout like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOf1x.png)
but i create layout like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFVeG.png)`
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Layout</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 bg-danger p-5 m-1">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 bg-success p-5 m-1">2</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 bg-success p-5 m-1">3</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 bg-success p-5 m-1">4</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 bg-success p-5 m-1">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 bg-warning p-5 m-1">6</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 bg-warning p-5 m-1">7</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 bg-primary p-5 m-1">8</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 bg-primary p-5 m-1">9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to create layout like 1st image